# Chess - console to GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, console, chess

I'm attempting to move my console-based chess game to a GUI. I'm currently referencing the [this chess tutorial](http://roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/chess-application-swing.shtml) to help get me started. I'm currently setting only one white rook on the board for testing purposes. In my console chess program, I have a Rook Class that determines how the Rook can move, what color it is, and so on.

In the tutorial code, they add a piece to the board like so:

```
    // Add a few pieces to the board    
    JLabel piece = new JLabel("rl.png");
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
    panel.add(piece);

//  my Attempt ---------------------------------------------------//

//      String rook = "Rook";
//      ImageIcon image4 = new ImageIcon("rl.png");
//      Rook firstRook = new Rook(rook, image4);
//      
//      piece = new JLabelfirstRook);
//      panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
//      panel.add(piece);
```

The rook can then be moved all over the board as it does not have any move rules applying to it. I want to hook up my rook class to the JLabel piece, so that the rook is bound by the move rules. Thus, my question:

**How can I hook up my console Rook Class to the Rook on the board?** And is there is a better way of doing this? Any help is appreciated, I've already scoured the internet for help on this and haven't been successful. Thanks!

My Rook Class:

```
public class RookTest extends ChessPiece
{ 

String name;
ImageIcon visualRep; //= new ImageIcon("rl.png");

public RookTest(String name, ImageIcon visualRep)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.visualRep = visualRep; 
}   

public String setInBoard() {
    return "| " + name + " |";
}


public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getColor()
{
    String pieceColor = null;
    if (name.equals("r"))
    {
        pieceColor = "d";
    }
    else if (name.equals("R"))
    {
        pieceColor = "l";
    }
    return pieceColor;  
}

public String toString() {
    //something to find the color in here
    return "Rook";
}

//legal moves
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

public boolean legalMove(ChessPiece[][] chess, int startY, int startX, int endY, int endX) 
{
    boolean thisIsAValidMove = false;

    //MOVING NORTH-SOUTH //if its in the same column and not in the same row//
    if (startY == endY && startX != endX ) 
        thisIsAValidMove = true;

    //MOVING EAST-WEST // if its in the same row but not the same column//
    else if(startX == endX && startY != endY)
        thisIsAValidMove = true;
    else
        thisIsAValidMove = false;
    return thisIsAValidMove;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: *"Tutorial at http://roseindia.."*  Stop right there.  Rose India is generally considered to be the single worst source of programming information on the net (quite an achievement).  Stop using it and go to the 'next hit in the search results'.

Comment: Oh? I had no idea. Could you suggest any other helpful resources then? I have already scoured the internet on this topic and that resource has been the most helpful so far.

Comment: While I agree that the material at RoseIndia isn't the best specially when it comes to the best practices. That said, its not too bad for someone starting out as they present the material in a way which is easy to understand.

Comment: At the mouse up event once you have moved the piece are you calling the legalMove function?
In the tutorial, after you compute the final position in mouseReleased you should only place the piece in the new position if legalMove returns true. If you need more help then please share the working code on someplace like github so we can take a look.

Comment: In this case, I just need the piece to register as a rook-- check out my attempt in the first code section i provided. I'm trying to get the JPanel piece to equal an instance of the Rook Class. I can test to see if the piece was a rook by using getName. To solve the stated problem, Step 1 would be to instantiate the Jlabel piece  as  a Rook. If i can figure that out, I will be able to figure out how to do legalMove.

Comment: Is the aim here to implement your own GUI, or just to get it working in >a< GUI? If the latter, I might suggest implementing a chess protocol such as [Winboard](http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/WinBoard/engine-intf.html) or [UCI](http://www.wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html‎), then plugging it into one of the many existing chess GUIs such as [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/‎). This has the additional advantage of making it much easier to pit your engine against other engines!